# Is there a thinner tool card than the Victorinox Swiss Card?

Tags: gear

I often use a [Swiss](http://www.victorinox.com/us/product/Swiss-Army-Knives/Category/Everyday-Use/SwissCard-Lite/53331) [Card](http://www.swissarmy.com/us/app/product/Swiss-Army-Knives/Category/Everyday-Use/SwissCard-Lite/53331) as my catch-all pocket knife replacement while travelling, as it's light and easy to keep in your pocket (save for plane flights, obviously).

However I've found the width of it an obstacle to storing it in wallets, etc.  At about 5 mm (or 0.2 inches) it's decidedly thicker than a credit card or drivers license, which is what most wallets are designed around.

Is there a thinner tool card around that, at a minimum, provides scissors and preferably tweezers (my most commonly used features)?  I've been struggling to find one so thought I could use the wisdom of the masses to see if I'm just managing to not stumble across one that does exist.

Comment: The link is broken.

Comment: Weird, it still goes through to the site fine when I click it.  Is http://www.victorinox.com/us/category/Collections/SwissCards/1023?f=category&v=1/101/1023&m=add& any better?

Comment: > HTTP Status 500 - Cannot find CMSSite associated with current URL

Comment: The link works for me as-is. May be a problem with the remote web site.

Comment: Ok, added link to a different server.

Comment: Neither links work for me. [Is this one OK?](http://www.victorinox.com/ch/product/Swiss-Army-Knives/Category/SwissCards/SwissCards/SwissCard-Lite/0.7300.T)

Comment: It's not the server that is broken, it's a country oriented redirection ( /us/ ). A user located in a different country would most likely not be able to use it.

Answer (score 3):

At this moment there is nothing available that has all the functionality. However check out the following link. My boyfriend found this during his Europe visits.

http://www.ukase.co.uk/tag/victorinox-swiss-card-lite-jelly-onyx-reviews/

However I've heard that a new carbon fiber version is going to be available which will be super thin at 2.45mm.